# RcppTN .cpp script works when sourced but not when compiled in library

Tags: r, rcpp

I am trying to create a R package that uses random draws from a truncated normal in a .cpp script. I am using the rtn1 function from the pckage RcppTN. If I source the code, the function works fine. Once I build the package I get the error:

```
> library(testtruncnorm)
> testtruncnorm()
Error in testtruncnorm::testtruncnorm() :
  function 'RcppTN_rtn1' not provided by package 'RcppTN'
```

Simplified .cpp code is here

```cpp
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppTN.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppTN)]]
#include<armadillo>
using namespace Rcpp;

//' draw truncated normal
//'
//' testtruncnorm() 
//' @return returns 2 draws from a truncated normal
// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::vec testtruncnorm()
{
  arma::vec result = arma::ones(2);
  result[1] = RcppTN::rtn1(1, 1, 0,HUGE_VAL);
  result[2] = RcppTN::rtn1(1, 1, 0,HUGE_VAL);

  return result; 
 }
```

My NAMESPACE file is

```
useDynLib(testtruncnorm, .registration=TRUE)
importFrom(Rcpp, evalCpp)
exportPattern("^[[:alpha:]]+")
```

My DESCRIPTION file is

```
Package: testtruncnorm
Type: Package
Title: What the Package Does Using Title Case
Version: 1.0
Date: 2018-10-23
Author: Your Name
Maintainer: Your Name <your@email.com>
Description: More details about what the package does. See
     <http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#The- 
DESCRIPTION-file>
     for details on how to write this part.
License: GPL (>= 2)
Imports: Rcpp (>= 0.12.19), RcppTN
LinkingTo: Rcpp, RcppArmadillo, RcppTN
```

I am using RStudio create "R Package with RcppArmadillo" to get started. RStudio version 1.1.456. R version 3.5.1. Windows 10.

Comment: The answer below by Ralf Stubner should fix the problem you're posting about, but you will also want to note that C++ is 0-indexed, not 1-indexed like R, so you will want to decrement by one the indices you have up there to avoid segfault. (i.e. change `result[1]` to `result[0]` and `result[2]` to `result[1]`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make sure that `RcppTN` gets attached. You can do this using

```
importFrom(RcppTN, rtn)
```

in `NAMESPACE`. In the documentation for `RcppTN` it says that one should add

```
Depends: RcppTN
```

which should have the same effect.

Comment: Good addition.  We may add that "these days" `Depends:` are discouraged and `Imports:`, which require the line in `NAMESPACE`, are preferred.